# Filter dataframe with list of nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Sample data ,I have a dataframe 'df' :

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HH | DOG |
| 2 | HH | CAT |
| 3 | W | DOG |

have one variable as list of nested dict filter_dict = [{'a': 'HH'}, {'a': 'W','b':'DOG'}]

How can I filter the dataframe directly through one of it's function with using looping?

Expected output :

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HH | DOG |
| 2 | HH | CAT |
| 3 | W | DOG |

Now I want another filter to exclude on the basis of with the same logic you guys did on merge but now remove_dict = [{'a': 'HH', 'b':'CAT'}]

Expected output :

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HH | DOG |
| 3 | W | DOG |

Requirement is I have a huge dataframe in which I have to include on the basis of values which is in dict(dynamic values and columns) and then exclude on the basis of another dict

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @tomjn updated in question only

Comment: a = [{'a': 'HH','b': 'DOG'}, {'a': 'W','b':'DOG'}] should be your dict to achieve this output?

Comment: @pythonic833 I think the OP wants to be able to filter based on the values of the columns 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: @NITINKOTHARI: just as Hamza usman ghani pointed out, please update your dictionary.

Comment: thank you all but i have changed my question a little bit just want to remove as well @Hamzausmanghani

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you want to create a dataframe from your 'filter dictionary' and then `pd.merge` based upon the columns of interest to get the intersection. To find the difference, you can do the same, and the use the `id` column to drop the intersecting id's from the original dataframe.

```python
import pandas as pd


def filter_df(df, filter_dict, option='keep'):

    x = pd.concat([pd.merge(df, pd.DataFrame([dic]), 
                            how ='inner',
                            on=list(dic.keys()))
                   for dic in filter_dict], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()
    if option == "keep":
        return x
    elif option == "exclude":
        return df[df["id"].isin(x["id"].values) == False]
    else:
        NotImplementedError(f"Option {option} not implemented. Please choose between 'keep' and 'exclude'.")
```

Here are the test cases:

```python
data = {"id": [1,2,3], "a": ["HH", "HH", "W"], "b": ["DOG", "CAT", "DOG"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# test case 1
filter_dict_1 = [{'a': 'HH'}, {'a': 'W','b':'DOG'}]
df1 = filter_df(df, filter_dict_1, "keep")
print(df1)
# #    id   a    b
# 0   1  HH  DOG
# 1   2  HH  CAT
# 2   3   W  DOG


# test case 2
filter_dict_2 = [{'a': 'HH', 'b': 'CAT'}]
df2 = filter_df(df, filter_dict_2, "exclude")
print(df2)
#   id   a    b
#0   1  HH  DOG
#2   3   W  DOG


# # test case 3
filter_dict_3 = [{'a': 'HH', 'b':'CAT'}, {"a": 'HH'}]
df3 = filter_df(df, filter_dict_3, "exclude")
print(df3)
#   id  a    b
#2   3  W  DOG
```

Comment: can I use this approach? I can merge on the columns of df1, something like : int_df = pd.merge(df, df1, how ='inner', on =df1.columns.values.tolist()) but how will I exclude (Like in the below answer we use uranry opertor)

Comment: @NITINKOTHARI, yes, I have updated the answer to use the merge approach to keep or exclude based on the filter_dict.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a generic solution, where you don't even need to know the columns of specified in filter_dict you can use a double reduce:

```python
from functools import reduce
from operator import invert

def filter_df(df, filter_dict, option='keep'):
    slice_vector = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [reduce(lambda x, y: 
                                                      x & y, [df[col] == val for col, val in el.items()])
                          for el in filter_dict])
    if option == 'keep':
        return df.loc[slice_vector]
    elif option == 'exclude':
        return df.loc[invert(slice_vector)]
    else:
        NotImplementedError(f"Option {option} not implemented. Please choose between 'keep' and 'exclude'.")
```

Let's apply this on various test cases:

```
data = {"id": [1,2,3], "a": ["HH", "HH", "W"], "b": ["DOG", "CAT", "DOG"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# test case 1
filter_dict_1 = [{'a': 'HH'}, {'a': 'W','b':'DOG'}]
df1 = filter_df(df, filter_dict_1, "keep")
print(df1)
#    id   a    b
# 0   1  HH  DOG
# 1   2  HH  CAT
# 2   3   W  DOG


# test case 2
filter_dict_2 = [{'a': 'HH', 'b': 'CAT'}]
df2 = filter_df(df, filter_dict_2, "exclude")
print(df2)
#   id   a    b
#0   1  HH  DOG
#2   3   W  DOG


# test case 3
filter_dict_3 = [{'a': 'HH', 'b':'CAT'}, {"a": 'HH'}]
df3 = filter_df(df, filter_dict_3, "exclude")
print(df3)
#   id  a    b
#2   3  W  DOG
```

The idea is that we first create a boolean vector based on the single dictionaries. These vectors are created by combining the single conditions with `&` and then combine these vectors to the final filtering vector with `|`.

Comment: @NITINKOTHARI, since in your updated question the number of keys in the dictionary can vary, I would use this solution. Changing the logical operators can reverse the logical from keeping to removing. (I will update the examples in this answer for you).

Comment: thanks a lot @PeterCurran and @ pythonic833, This works exactly as required by when I'm trying to commit the code  one pylint issue occurs  : E1130: bad operand type for unary ~: object (invalid-unary-operand-type) for this line : "return df.loc[~slice_vector]"

don't want to disable it, could you please tell me how it can be resolved?

Comment: @NITINKOTHARI not sure what's causing this but you could try replacing `~slice_vector` with `operator.invert(slice_vector)`

Comment: @NITINKOTHARI: this seems to be a known issue with numpy and pandas structures where pylint is throwing unnecessary warnings as you can see [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/2436). It would be safe to disable them here. But I've also updated the answer to Peter Curran's suggestions so that no more warning should be thrown